# Can a ContentObserver be used with the new RecyclerView notifyItem functions?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-cursor

I am struggling to figure out how I can make use of the expanded set of notify functions that come in the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
final void notifyItemChanged(int position)
final void notifyItemInserted(int position)
final void notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition)
final void notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)
final void notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)
final void notifyItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)
final void notifyItemRemoved(int position)
```

This is my reasoning:

If I am using a ContentProvider to populate my RecyclerView, and a ContentObserver to inform the my RecyclerView Adapter of data set changes, the ContentObserver only has `onChange(boolean self, Uri uri)` to communicate changes to the adapter. This function alone does not provide enough information to properly distinguish which `notifyItem.....` function should be used.

Are these notify functions of the RecyclerView Adapter meant to be used with the `ContentObserver`? Or are they intended to be used in another manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [a reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/37gocz/what_is_the_proper_way_to_use_a/crmk1ml), credit goes to the original author [defer](https://www.reddit.com/user/defer).

> 1. Make the cursor swapable (i.e. add a `swapCursor(Cursor)` method to your adapter that changes the stored cursor and then calls
>      `notifyDataSetChanged()`).
> 2. `setHasStableIds(true)` in the adapter
> 3. Override `getItemId()` in the adapter to provide a unique id for each position, these unique ids should map directly to your database
>      ids which means that the adapter can easily cross-reference them with
>      previous states of the cursor.
> 4. When your content changes just call your new `swapCursor` method with the new cursor and it will use the unique ids to map the previous
>      state to the new one and automatically compute the appropriate
>      animations.
>
> Edit: I'm assuming you have a cursor, in fact it works with any
>   underlying data structure, the key is `setHasStableIds`, overriding
>   the `getItemId` function and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.